# projectile-rails: run the current test

Tags: projectile, testing, ruby

While it is easy to run the whole test suite with `projectile-rails`, this takes too much time. I'd like to be able to run the current test (i.e., the test point is located in) with a shortcut. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it works:

```
(defun get-current-test-name ()
  (save-excursion
    (let ((pos)
          (test-name))
      (re-search-backward "test \"\\([^\"]+\\)\" do")
      (setq test-name (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))
      (concat "test_" (replace-regexp-in-string " " "_" test-name)))))


(defun run-test-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((root-dir (projectile-project-root)))
    (compile (format "ruby -Ilib:test -I%s/test %s -n %s" root-dir (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name)) (get-current-test-name)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming rspec:

Install `rspec-mode`, which will activate itself automatically in `ruby-mode` or `enh-ruby-mode` then you can use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to run `rspec-verify-single` which will run the test at point.

Comment: Is there something similiar for `ActionController::TestCase`?

Comment: I do not know but writing your own wouldn't be hard, from what I see all you need to do is write code that gets the name of the test at point. then do something like this: `(let ((default-directory (get-project-root-from-projectile))) (compile (format "rake test %s %s" (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name)) (get-your-test-name))))`